# Retrofit - How to add header authorization with type bearer

Tags: android, api, retrofit, retrofit2, request-headers

```
@POST("requests")
Call<OrderResponse> getOrderAccess(@Header("Authorization") String token ,@Body OrderRequest orderRequest);
```

The Method below is not working, it is returning error 401 (unauthorized)
This is the following documentation of the API header:

Field: Authorization      Type: Bearer    Description: User token

The following is the code calling the above method where token is a string passed through intent on login

```
 Call<OrderResponse> tokenResponseCall = service.getOrderAccess(token, tokenRequest);

                tokenResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<OrderResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Response<OrderResponse> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

                        int statusCode = response.code();
                        if (response.code() == 401 || response.code()==400) {

                            Toast.makeText(MakeRequest.this, "Error ! "+response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                        else if (response.code()==200){
                            Toast.makeText(MakeRequest.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

                        Toast.makeText(MakeRequest.this, "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "Failure:" +t.getMessage());

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Are you sending "Bearer "+token while calling getOrderAccess function when making the function call? Please post the code where you have called the mentioned function